# Eclipse, PyDev and Python configuration error

Tags: python, eclipse, configuration, pydev

I decided to try to work with Eclipse and PyDev instead of IDLE.
I successfully "installed" Eclipse SDK 3.7.
After that, I followed the steps displayed on the PyDev website and successfully installed the plugin.
However, when trying to configure my interpreter (Python 3.2.3), I always get an error, and don't know how to fix this.
I cannot configure it neither automatically nor manually, and there is no reference to this error on the PyDev website.

When trying to configure it automatically, the message displayed is:

```
Unable to gather the needed info from the system.

This usually means that your interpreter is not in the system PATH.
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

When I try to configure it manually, the message displayed is the same, adding that some common causes for this problem may be incompatible versions. I have the latest Java (which is one of the requirements, Eclipse was downloaded just yesterday from their site and is 3.7 version (Indigo), and Python is version 3.2.3.

I even tried to add a folder containing the libraries, because, from what I understand, this would also do the trick. However, whenever I click the `New Folder` button, it does nothing...

I am running all this on Windows 7 32-bit.

If anyone can help me in this matter, I would be very grateful.

Thank you

```
> **@Fabio Zadrozny:** 
>
> 1: The path to the Python interpreter is C:\Python32\python.exe 
>
> 2: The message displayed when I ran the
> interpreterInfo.py was: 
>
> C:\Windows\system32>python
> C:\eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.python.p
> ydev_2.6.0.2012041219\PySrc\interpreterInfo.py 
> 
> <xml>
> <version>3.2</version> <executable>C:\Python32\python.exe</executable>
> <lib
> path="out">C:\eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.6.0.
> 2012041219\PySrc</lib> <lib path="ins">C:\Python32\MÓDULOS</lib> <lib
> path="out">C:\Windows\system32\python32.zip</lib> <lib
> path="ins">C:\Python32\DLLs</lib> <lib
> path="ins">C:\Python32\lib</lib> <lib path="ins">C:\Python32</lib>
> <lib path="ins">C:\Python32\lib\site-packages</lib>
> <forced_lib>__main__</forced_lib> <forced_lib>_ast</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_bisect</forced_lib> <forced_lib>_codecs</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_codecs_cn</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_codecs_hk</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_codecs_iso2022</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_codecs_jp</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_codecs_kr</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_codecs_tw</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_collections</forced_lib> <forced_lib>_csv</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_datetime</forced_lib> <forced_lib>_functools</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_heapq</forced_lib> <forced_lib>_io</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_json</forced_lib> <forced_lib>_locale</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_lsprof</forced_lib> <forced_lib>_md5</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_multibytecodec</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_pickle</forced_lib> <forced_lib>_random</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_sha1</forced_lib> <forced_lib>_sha256</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_sha512</forced_lib> <forced_lib>_sre</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_string</forced_lib> <forced_lib>_struct</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_subprocess</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_symtable</forced_lib> <forced_lib>_thread</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>_warnings</forced_lib> <forced_lib>_weakref</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>array</forced_lib> <forced_lib>atexit</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>audioop</forced_lib> <forced_lib>binascii</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>builtins</forced_lib> <forced_lib>cmath</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>errno</forced_lib> <forced_lib>gc</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>imp</forced_lib> <forced_lib>itertools</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>marshal</forced_lib> <forced_lib>math</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>mmap</forced_lib> <forced_lib>msvcrt</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>nt</forced_lib> <forced_lib>operator</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>parser</forced_lib> <forced_lib>signal</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>sys</forced_lib> <forced_lib>time</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>winreg</forced_lib> <forced_lib>xxsubtype</forced_lib>
> <forced_lib>zipimport</forced_lib> <forced_lib>zlib</forced_lib>
> </xml>Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.6.0.20120412
> 19\PySrc\interpreterInfo.py", line 142, in <module>
>     raise RuntimeError('Ok, this is so that it shows the output (ugly hack for s ome platforms, so that it releases the output).')
> RuntimeError: Ok, this is so that it shows the output (ugly hack for
> some platfo rms, so that it releases the output).
```

> Thank you for your
>   help! And sorry for the formatting.

Comment: Did you do the process Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreter->Python and select the path to the executable where Python 3.2.3 is located on your machine?

Comment: I did. Then Eclipse said:
"Error getting info on interpreter.
Common reasons include:
-Using an unsupported version(Python and Jython require at least... blah blah)
-Specifying an invalid interpreter(usually a link to the actual interpreter on Mac or Linux)
Reason:See error log for details"
and then there's that message I posted on top, beginning with com.sun....UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: Might want to give more details such as OS, version, bits (windows 64 bit is a bit of a PITA with the whole 32/64 bit coexistence thing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit 2:

This issue has just been fixed (and a nightly build has been deployed with the fix). This will be available on PyDev 2.6.0

---

Edit:

The issue seems to be a unicode issue because of C:\Python32\MÓDULOS. I'll try to fix that tomorrow, in the meanwhile, you can remove the unicode chars from your PYTHONPATH to make things work...

---

To properly diagnose it, please do the following:

Go to window > preferences > pydev > interpreter - python and choose the 'new' option to point to the actual python executable (I think you already did that, but just to make sure it's not only an issue in the auto config).

If the issue above doesn't solve it, I believe it may be unicode issue, so, to be able to help you, please follow the steps below:

1. Post your path to the Python interpreter you're configuring.
2. Run: python c:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_XXX\pysrc\interpreterInfo.py and paste the output you have.

   (make sure that 'python' is the python you're configuring and the path from the plugin points to the proper location).
3. If you have some unicode char in the path to your python interpreter, try installing python to some place where you don't have unicode chars (if this solves your issue, I'll take care of making it work with your configuration, but I'll probably only be able to tackle this on Thursday -- but it'll be really high-priority in my todo-list).

Comment: wow, a response from a pydev developer! this site is awesome.

Comment: I have the same problem as above, and installing Pydev 2.6 from the Nightly didn't solve the problem, I would try to uninstall and reinstall python and update.

Comment: i got <forced_lib>sys</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>thread</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>zipimport</forced_lib>
</xml>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interpreterInfo.py", line 199, in ?
    raise RuntimeError('Ok, this is so that it shows the output (ugly hack for some platforms, so that it releases the output).')
RuntimeError: Ok, this is so that it shows the output (ugly hack for some platforms, so that it releases the output).

Comment: the error just happened with the pydev 3.1! hope  this will be fixed again