# Trouble with python interpreter on Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using win7 - 64 bit .

I am trying to get the python plugin to work on eclipse.

I installed PyDev 2.7.1 plugin, and I downloaded Python 2.7.1 http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.1/

In Eclipse I go to window->preferences->PyDev->Interpreter-Python, and add the path to `C:\Python27\python.exe`

and then I get an error

See error log for details.

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

does anyone know what this means and how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10195111/3571

Comment: Try it with Python 2.7.3. The version number of PyDev does not have to match the version of Python being used, so you might as well use the latest release of version 2 Python.